# R. function. error

Tags: r, function

I have the following function f

```
f <- function (n) if (n==0) 1 else f(n - 1)(n %% 2) - f(n-1)(n+1)
```

I think it is defined right but I cannot calculate f(8)

```
f(8)

> Error in f(n - 1) : attempt to apply non-function
```

what do I have to change?

Comment: You're trying to calculate `f(n-1)` inside the function definition for `f(n)`. Are you trying to build a recursive function or something? Either way, your function is not defined correctly.

Comment: my `f(n)` is    `f(n - 1)(n %% 2) - f(n-1)(n+1)`

Comment: Is that supposed to be multiplication?  `f(n - 1)*(n %% 2) - f(n-1)*(n+1)` maybe? `f(8) # [1] 99225`

Comment: yes. `f(8) = f(8-1)*(8 %% 2).......`

Answer (score 0):

In R recursion is not terribly well optimised but the basic approach is to use the `Recall` function. It's unclear what you intend with the "double calling" syntax e.g. `f(n-1)(n+1)` where f is followed first by a parentheses paired with one argument and then another argument. The `f` function isn't being designed to return a function. I'm going to make a guess that you wanted the recurrence relation in f(n) to be:

```
 f(n - 1)*(n %% 2) - f(n-1)*(n+1)
```

If that guess is correct then:

```
 f <- function (n) if (n==0) 1 else {Recall(n - 1) *(n %% 2) - Recall(n-1)*(n+1)}

> f(8)
[1] 99225
```

I made my guess before the clarifying comments but appears I was correct in thinking you didn't understand that `f(n)(n %% 2)` was incorrect R syntax. Back to back parentheses (brackets in the English English language) are not signifying multiplication, but rather function application. Look at `?Syntax` and for an example see `?ecdf` where `ecdf(x)(n)` is an acceptable nested call because ecdf returns a function as a value.

Comment: Comments should not be used just for thanks, but .... upvotes and checkmarks should.